# How to lure spiders as Webber without attacking the nest?

Tags: dont-starve

I'm playing as Webber and I want to fight spiders during the day, so I would go up and smack the nest once with my spear to aggro the spiders. I thought this was okay, and that the nest would sort of "auto-repair" itself after a day, but after a few days of doing this the nest actually broke.

So how am I supposed to get the spiders to come out and attack me during the daytime without breaking the nest?

Comment: i think they eat monster meat? not sure you can try dropping it on the web to see if they come out, otherwise i guess you can lure a pig to lure the spiders out

Comment: The monster meat is a major source of food for my character, and unfortunately there are no pigs anywhere nearby my spider nest :/

Comment: you can always move the spider nest to a pig house, or build a pig house near a spider nest

Comment: and I did some researching, they'll only go for the food at dusk, which isn't what you want, so the pigs I think are the way to go

Comment: In lieu of fighting them, you can also scatter traps around their nest.  They'll roam at evening and night and get caught.  Then in the morning you can go collect from the traps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a Pig House near the Spider Den, the pigs will lure out the spiders and will even kill them for you, so you only have to come back every now and then to collect your spider (and pig) loot.

You can also build a Spider Den near some Pig Houses instead to achieve the same thing.

A Pig House can be built with 4 Boards, 3 Cut stone and 4 Pig Skins.

A Spider Den can be built with 12 Silk, 6 Spider Glands, and 6 Papyrus.

Comment: I guess this answer is correct, but just for the sake of my situation and curiosity, is there a way to do it without pigs? (Because there has literally not been a single pig on this map plus they are hostile to me.)

Comment: The pigs only come out of their houses during the day (and sometimes at the full moon).  So you could always put some spider nests in a pig village at dusk (or night), and thereafter only collect the loot at dusk (or night).